# How do you make a panel show multiple things one after another? (java)

Tags: java, swing, animation, jpanel, thread-sleep

I have a class that extends JPanel (and it's like a game setup). In this class, I have a method which loops through my `animate/display` method 8 times using a for loop and a `Thread.sleep()`. My `animate/display` method first calls the `removeAll()` method, adds a JLabel onto the panel, then revalidates and repaints. For some reason, when I add this class to a JFrame and try to run it, the JFrame stays blank until the final run-through of the loop, and then only the final JLabel is displayed. (I tested out changing the number of times the for loop runs- no matter how many times it runs, the last one is the only one that shows up). Previously, this class used to extend JFrame instead of JPanel, but I had to change it to a JPanel for the purposes of my game. It worked perfectly fine as a JFrame- all the JLabels showed up when they were supposed to. When I tried to write the exact same code (with a few slight modifications) as a JPanel, it suddenly has this problem with only the last JLabel showing up. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

*CODE*

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

    public class HardLevel extends JPanel{

      public HardLevel(){
      super();
      runGame();
      setVisible(true);
      setSize(683,500);
    }

    public void runGame(){
      for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
         animate();
         try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException a){}
      }
    }

    public void animate(){
        int num = 0;
        num = (int)(Math.random() * 13 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        removeAll();
        JLabel desc = new JLabel("Scene number "+num);
        desc.setFont(desc.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20));
        desc.setForeground(Color.RED);
        desc.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        desc.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        add (desc);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
      }
   }
```

Above is a simplified version of the class that Extends JPanel

```
HardLevel h = new HardLevel();
removeAll();
add(h);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Above is the code I'm using when I'm adding this to the JFrame

**EDIT**

This is my first time working with Swing in a complex context, so I don't really know much about the EDT or anything related to that.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the looping in the event dispatch thread, blocking it. (And the old version was running the loop in another thread, probably the main thread). Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the delays, never `sleep()` in the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TimerTask to repeatedly cycle through what you want to set data on the JPanel to.

check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Hard to tell what's wrong with your implementation without seeing your code.

Comment: No, don't use a TimerTask. Updates to the GUI should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use a Swing Timer. It executes on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr is correct. TimerTask would work but is definitely not the best route to go. Sorry about that,

Answer (score 0):

The method repaint() use to repaint all the Frame. You can't repaint only a JPanel. Try to add the JPanel to a JFrame and repaint everything. Use Frame.add(JPanel); However the method Thread.sleep() stop the execution off all the task. It may create problems.

Comment: `You can't repaint only a JPanel` - yes you can. You just to `panel.repaint()`.